# Dropzone image upload error display how to remove error

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

**Notes :** i tired all questions & answer  related this  topic.

**I want to remove HTML data in popup after upload img or other document in Dropzone .**

Dropzone uploed file accepted are assign 
`var accept = ".png";` Work Fine. **see code** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/mxxa0bk8/6/) .But after image or other file upload then some html are display

[image]

**snippet Example Below.**

```js
var accept = ".png";
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

// Dropzone class:
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#mydropzone", { 
  url: "/file/post",
   acceptedFiles: accept,
   uploadMultiple: false,
   createImageThumbnails: false,
   addRemoveLinks: true,
    maxFiles: 3,
    maxfilesexceeded: function(file) {
        this.removeAllFiles();
        this.addFile(file);
    }
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/dropzone.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/basic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clsbox-1" runat="server"  >
  <div class="dropzone clsbox" id="mydropzone">

  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is caused because you are running the code in a fiddle, and dropzone is trying to upload the files to an url that doesn't exists.

When dropzone gets an error displays the message received by the server in the red popup, in this case is an html page.

This will not happen when you upload the files to a valid url.

You can change the text in the popup like this.

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#mydropzone", {
  url: "/file/post",
  acceptedFiles: accept,
  uploadMultiple: false,
  createImageThumbnails: false,
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  maxFiles: 3,
  maxfilesexceeded: function(file) {
    this.removeAllFiles();
    this.addFile(file);
  },
  init: function() {
    this.on('error', function(file, errorMessage) {
      if (errorMessage.indexOf('Error 404') !== -1) {
        var errorDisplay = document.querySelectorAll('[data-dz-errormessage]');
        errorDisplay[errorDisplay.length - 1].innerHTML = 'Error 404: The upload page was not found on the server';
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Or while you are in a fiddle you can just pretend the upload was successful by just changing a class.

```
init: function() {
  this.on('error', function(file, errorMessage) {
    if (file.accepted) {
      var mypreview = document.getElementsByClassName('dz-error');
      mypreview = mypreview[mypreview.length - 1];
      mypreview.classList.toggle('dz-error');
      mypreview.classList.toggle('dz-success');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: thak you for answer . but i set your  code in my fiddle error remove but all error remove ..if you can upload wrong document then not popup. so i want to popup are allow but .remove in successfully upload document then remove error . not wrong document upload .. see my fiddle upload any `pdf `file then not popup .https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/mxxa0bk8/8/

Comment: @Sumitpatel just updated the answer to remove the error only on the accepted files. My suggestion is that if you need to develop things that relay on response from server, you may want to switch from jsfiddle to something that can provide responses like an actual server. Take a look at "plunker" or "code.runnable" both are free, if you want to do it online, also consider setting up your own enviroment.